# How can I set the width and height of a rectangle in webgl?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I'm new to webgl so for now I can only draw simple triangles and rectangles. I have a game I finished with Canvas's 2d API. But unfortunately the performance can be very bad sometimes. So I decided to convert my game to webgl. I can't adjust the Width and Height of the rectangle I've drawn. My code is as below.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// Create a vertex shader
var vertexShaderSource = `
  attribute vec3 a_position;

  void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
  }
`;

var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

// Create a fragment shader
var fragmentShaderSource = `
  precision mediump float;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
`;
var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

// Create a program and attach the shaders
var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  console.error("Could not link program:", gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
}

gl.useProgram(program);

// Create a buffer to hold the vertices
var vertices = [  
  0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
  0.5, -0.5, 0.0
];

var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// Bind the vertex buffer to the position attribute
var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

function animate() {
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to adjust the size of the polygon you are drawing.

Then you should probably work with **matrices**. A simple exemple should be:

```js
/* vertices positions of your polygon */
let vertPositions = [
  0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
  0.5, -0.5, 0.0
];

/* width and height of your polygon */
let size = {width: 2, height: 1};

/* scaling matrix */
let scalingMatrix = [size.width, 0.0,
                     0.0,       size.height];
```

Then you can send this matrix to your **vertex shader** like so:

```js
let mObjectSizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation("mObjectSize", program);
gl.uniformMatrix2fv(mObjectSizeLocation, new Float32Array(scalingMatrix));
```

*`program` is the **WebGLProgram** you are using to store your **vertex** & **fragment** shaders.*

And update your vertex shader to this:

```c
attribute vec3 a_position;

uniform mat2 mObjectSize;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = mObjectSize * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

You can combine the **scaling matrix** with other matrices, a **translation matrix** for the position and a **rotation matrix** for the orientation. You should check [Learn Opengl](https://learnopengl.com/), even if the tutorial is for 3D, it can helps you a lot with 2D.

As a side note: you should use webgl2, there are much more things you can do with it.

Comment: I solved this problem a long time ago. Sorry for seeing your reply late.